# Why does the Pratt & Whitney 747 have an extra engine on the right side but not left side?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, boeing-747

[image]

What’s the purpose of this design, and why only on one side?

Comment: You should add a reference to the original picture. I'm quite sure this is a [testbed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testbed_aircraft) and its goal is to test the extra engine in flight (i.e. this engine is not here to provide thrust)

Comment: A good question would have been "why do they add a pylon instead of replacing one existing engine with the tested one?"

Comment: @ManuH True, but that question can only be asked once you know this 747 is a test bed. The additional engine might as well provide extra thrust or just get [carried around](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24181/18733), like Quantas did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an engine testbed aircraft. In this particular picture, the tested engine is probably one of the [PW1X00G series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_PW1000G) (mainly used by Airbus A220, Airbus A320neo, Embraer E-Jets E2, Irkut MC-21, Mitsubishi SpaceJet) and the aircraft is one of two Boeing 747SP testbed aircraft owned by PW.

Engine testbed aircraft test the engines in-flight, with parameters and conditions that can not be tested in a static test on the ground (for example, low temperatures and non-static thrust).

Engine testbed aircraft often end up in unusual configurations. Other examples include (but not limited to):

- General Electrics Boeing 747 testbeds: [1](https://www.ge.com/reports/how-do-you-test-the-worlds-largest-jet-engine-ges-chief-test-pilot-has-the-answers/) [2](https://www.ge.com/reports/time-flies-ges-original-flying-testbed-jets-off-history/)
- Honeywell's Boeing 757 testbed: [many pictures with different engines, even turboprops](https://www.air-and-space.com/20100201%20N757HW.htm).