# Can aircraft ferry engines for other types of aircraft?

Tags: engine, boeing-747, ferry-flight

There have been a number of questions that highlighted the fact that the 747 could ferry an engine on an underwing pod.

Was the 747 only capable of ferrying 747 engines? Or was it possible to ferry engines for other types of aircraft?

If it can only ferry 747 engines, is there, or has there ever been, an aircraft that can, and has, ferried engines of other aircraft types?

Edit: Following the comments and the one answer posted to date - ideally, I'm looking for cases of aircraft that can ferry engines externally for other types of aircraft. However, if no such case exists (and I suspect this to be the case), it would be nice to see more comprehensive details of how engines are ferried around the world (I'm sure i.e. Qantas won't always  use sea cargo, nor an An-124 to)

Comment: Maybe not, because the Virgin Orbit 747's hardpoint was "extensively modified" to carry the LauncherOne rocket.  So adapting the hardpoint to other engines might just cost too much, compared to what else the engineers might work on.  Photos I found of 707s and DC-8s and TriStars ferrying showed them only carrying their own kind of engine.

Comment: Would [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/how-are-off-wing-jet-engines-transported/8341#8341) answer your question?

Comment: @PeterKämpf I think at best it's only a partial answer - that skymonster is custom built as opposed to a standard aircraft with this curious feature.

Comment: Raytheon [regularly straps different engines to its 747](https://www.raytheon.com/news/feature/rtn_rollsroyce) as part of a testing program. An appropriate search is "engine test bed aircraft", you'll get numerous examples. Note, this isn't specific to ferrying (although it could be used for that), these are mainly test platforms.

Comment: @RonBeyer Interesting yes, but it's a modification to replace an engine for testing purposes. However, they're not ferrying the engine. There are plenty of photos of commercial flights ferrying an engine, but I'm curious to know whether it's possible to ferry an engine for a different type of aircraft.

Comment: We used to haul engines all the time in the C-130.  If you want to limit this to mounting it externally then you should specify that.

Comment: What sort of engines?  At the lower end, I would imagine that Lycoming & Continental engines get shipped by air freight fairly often.  From there up, why would shipping engines be any different from shipping any other freight?  As long as it fits in the cargo bay, why not?

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24181/can-the-a380-ferry-an-extra-engine-like-the-747

Comment: @Holmez You did note that the answer also says that most engines fit inside the 747, didn't you?

Comment: @PeterKämpf I did notice that. I guess the answer is going to be that most smaller engines can be ferried as internally carried cargo, and that certain types of aircraft, such as the 747, can ferry engines of their own type on underwing pods.How about ferrying of 777 or 380 engines? Can they be carried as internal cargo?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.aviationpros.com/aircraft/commercial-airline/press-release/12308350/antonov-airlines-transports-worlds-most-powerful-turbofan-engine-to-grounded-aircraft-in-canadian-arctic)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

The Antonov 124 regularly ferries even the largest engine, the GE9X, internally. Нема проблем!

[image: GE9X being loaded into the An-124]

GE9X being loaded into the An-124 (picture [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PMJg-N0ICI))